# MYSQL - Inner Join problems

Tags: php, mysql, forms, inner-join

It is my first time doing this.
I am having a number of issues, when it comes to inner joining two tables.
What i am trying to do is display/echo out details from two tables in a form field, when the user signs into their account.
I can successfully echo out details from one table, the moment i try to inner join the second table the webpage literally shows nothing, even though i have content.

This is the error that appears

> "fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PhpProject2/customer/Cus_Account.php:24 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PhpProject2/customer/Cus_Account.php on line 24"

line 24 is:

```
 $row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

PHP

```
  $results = $dbc->query("SELECT Cus_Register.Cus_Email FROM Cus_Register INNER JOIN
   Cus_acc_details ON Cus_Register.Cus_Email = Cus_acc_details.Cus_Email WHERE
  Cus_acc_details WHERE Cus_Email='$user'");
 $row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['Cus_Email'] = $row['Cus_Email'];
?>
<!-- update database-->
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['Update'])){

$UpdateFname =  $_POST['fname'];
$UpdateLname =  $_POST['Lname'];
$UpdateEmail =  $_POST['email'];
$UpdatePhone =  $_POST['phone'];
}
$sql = $dbc->query("UPDATE Cus_Register,Cus_acc_details SET CUS_Fname = '      $UpdateFname', CUS_Lname = ' $UpdateLname', CUS_Email = ' $UpdateEmail', Cus_Phone = ' $UpdatePhone' WHERE CUS_Email = ")
?>
```

HTML

```
   <section class="container">
    <form id="myform " class="Form" method="post" action="Cus_Account.php?c_id=<?php echo $c_id ?>" accept-charset="utf-8">

        <!--                    <div id="first">-->
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"  value="<?php echo $_SESSION['CUS_Fname']; ?>" required> 
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"  value="<?php echo $_SESSION['CUS_Lname']; ?>" required>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Cus_Email']; ?>" required>
        <input type="number" id="phone" name="phone" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['CUS_Phone']; ?>"  required>
        <input type="submit" name="Update" value="Update">
        <br>
    </form>
```

Comment: you have a whole bunch of spaces in `= ' $` which count as characters and `WHERE CUS_Email = ")` seems incomplete.

Comment: Note that your query is wide open for SQL injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select statement is:

```
SELECT Cus_Register.Cus_Email
FROM Cus_Register INNER JOIN
     Cus_acc_details
     ON Cus_Register.Cus_Email = Cus_acc_details.Cus_Email
WHERE  Cus_acc_details WHERE Cus_Email='$user';
```

This is not valid SQL.  I suspect you intend this:

```
SELECT r.Cus_Email
FROM Cus_Register r INNER JOIN
     Cus_acc_details d
     ON r.Cus_Email = d.Cus_Email
WHERE r.Cus_Email = '$user';
```

A single `SELECT` has only one `WHERE` clause.

Your `UPDATE` is also suspicious because it has two tables connect by a comma.  However, I cannot tell what the right logic would be in that case.

Comment: This whole line `$sql = $dbc->query("UPDATE Cus_Register,Cus_acc_details SET CUS_Fname = '...` doesn't hold water here.